# Create input dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to insert an input(type=file) when I click the button using js but the input element appear for miliseconds and then right after it dissapears.
Here's my code:

```
function addInputImg(){
            var div2 = document.getElementById("imgFiles");
            var inputImg = document.createElement('input');
            inputImg.type = 'file';
            div2.appendChild(inputImg);     
        }
<form ...>
.
.
<button id='btnAgregarImg' onclick="addInputImg();">Agregar imagen</button>
<div  id='imgFiles'>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the button type to "button" to prevent the form from being submitted.

https://jsfiddle.net/g5Lxr2ac/

```
<button id='btnAgregarImg' type="button" onclick="addInputImg();">Agregar imagen</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Button `<button>` inside a `form` element are treated like a `submit` button by default. In your case, when you are pressing the button inside the form, the form is getting submitted and the page gets `reloaded` every time.

Try to set your button's type `attribute` as `button` to avoid this issue.

```
<button type="button" id='btnAgregarImg' onclick="addInputImg();">Agregar imagen</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<button id='btnAgregarImg' onclick="addInputImg();">Agregar imagen</button>
```

To this:

```
<button id='btnAgregarImg' type="button" onclick="addInputImg();">Agregar imagen</button>
```